# How to fix ipython installation "Operation not permitted" error?

Tags: python, macos, pip, installation, ipython

I'm trying to install ipython by running `sudo pip install ipython` and i get this error in my Mac OSX El captain 10.11.6. Please help. Thank you.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/qp/926rqdqj5jd7lpywngyh002h00c_zb/T/pip-N6qHvL-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install jupyter` instead?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error is known, in fact after the **OSX El captain** upgrade, many users have the same problem with pip in general, not with a specific package.

If you are using your personal machine, you can try to install it in this way:

```
sudo pip install --user ipython
```

The `--user` parameter is the simplest solution.

Let me know if it works.